# How to replace Space with Line Break in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace

I am trying to replace Space in a string with Line Break in Ruby on Rails,

```
name = 'john smith'
```

i have tried the following so far:

```
name.gsub!(" ", "\n")   
name.gsub!(" ", "<br>")

name.sub(" ", "\n")   
name.sub(" ", "<br>")
```

but none of the above worked.

Comment: _"none of the above worked"_ – what does that mean? Any errors or unexpected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While printing it in html you will need to use [**`raw`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw), otherwise rails will escape the tags

```
= raw name.gsub(" ", "<br>")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful when marking a string as `html_safe`, especially if it may contain user input:

```
name = 'john smith<script>alert("gotcha")</script>'

name.gsub(' ', '<br>').html_safe
#=> "john<br>smith<script>alert(\"gotcha\")</script>"
```

Rails would output that string as-is, i.e. including the `<script>` tag.

In order to take advantage of Rails' HTML escaping, you should only mark the trusted parts as being `html_safe`. For a manually concatenated string:

```
''.html_safe + 'john' + '<br>'.html_safe + 'smith<script>alert("gotcha")</script>'
#=> "john<br>smith&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;gotcha&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;"
```

As you can see, only the `<br>` tag was left intact, the remaining parts were properly escaped.

There are several helpers for building safe strings as well as for building HTML tags. In your case, I'd use [`safe_join`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join) and [`tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag):

```
name = 'john smith<script>alert("gotcha")</script>'

safe_join(name.split(' '), tag(:br))
#=> "john<br />smith&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;gotcha&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;"
```

Comment: thanks for this useful information, really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Try another one:

```
<%= name.gsub(" ", "<br>").html_safe %>
```

- html_safe :

Marks a string as trusted safe. It will be inserted into HTML with no additional escaping performed.

```
"<a>Hello</a>".html_safe
#=> "<a>Hello</a>"

nil.html_safe
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass
```

- raw :

raw is just a wrapper around html_safe. Use raw if there are chances that the string will be nil.

```
raw("<a>Hello</a>")
#=> "<a>Hello</a>"

raw(nil)
#=> ""
```